# Can I use a compiled ReasonReact component together with the CDN version of React?

Tags: reactjs, reason

As the title states, I'd like to compile a small web component using Reason and React, and embed it on in web app that uses React via CDN, meaning no build step at all. Possible?

Comment: "Compile" implies "has a build step". What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @tadman Correct, ReasonReact will compile and build, but the other parts of the app use the CDN version of React. Can they be combined, is what I'm wondering.

Comment: Wait, I think I remember. I had problems with `import * as React from "react"`. This line is more or less hard-coded, it can't be configured in the bsb build chain.